# How to pipe from clipboard to firefox?

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, clipboard

This might be a amateur question. But I have a problem with piping.
I want to pipe my clipboard to firefox via the terminal.
In my clipboard is a url like https://www.google.com. Than I want open firefox like

```
firefox https://www.google.com
```

Now I want to replace the google URL by something of my clipboard. I tried to pipe it like:

```
xclip -o -selection clipboard | firefox
xclip -o -selection clipboard > url ; firefox url
xclip -o -selection clipboard > url ; cat url | firefox /dev/fd/0
```

All 3 aren't working.

Any suggestions on how I could solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox only takes URLs as *command line parameters*, not as stdin, and these are distinct things. So the pipe is not broken, it's just the wrong tool.

You need one of the following:

- "Command substitution" using the `$(…)` or `` `…` `` operators:

  ```
  firefox $(xclip -o -selection clipboard)
  ```
- A program which *does* take input from stdin, and *converts* it to command-line arguments:

  ```
  xclip -o -selection clipboard | xargs firefox
  ```